# How can I set a breakpoint in a cshtml file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, dynamic, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging some code contained in a cshtml file, within an MVC application. If I put a deliberate error in the code, then Visual Studio (2010) gives me the option to break on that line, at which point I can watch local variables etc. The file at this point is tagged as [dynamic].

I would like to put a breakpoint in the file without having to break the code with a deliberate error, and I thought it was possible to get up a list of currently loaded (dynamic) files and put a breakpoint in one of them, but if I search on such things as "dynamic" and "cshtml" I get nowhere.

I suspect this should be easy, but I can't work out how to do it! Hoping you can help.

Comment: Aha! I think I just answered my own question (but I'm a newbie here, so it won't let me post it as an answer). The Solution Explorer has a list of currently-loaded scripts in the Solution Explorer, under "Script Documents".
I tried looking there but couldn't find my code because it is contained in a file named Index.cshtml, but is within an MVC view named something else, and that's the name listed in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! The Solution Explorer has a list of currently-loaded scripts in the Solution Explorer, under "Script Documents". I tried looking there but couldn't find my code because it is contained in a file named Index.cshtml, but is within an MVC view named something else, and that's the name listed in the solution explorer.